# Qt - how to use layouts in Qt designer

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets, qlayout

I have some troubles in using layouts. as you know Qt designer has some layouts by default but they cant help me. in the widgets bar in layouts section there are some customized layouts but I cant use them , they are actually do nothing when i insert them into my ui. now anyone can help me to use them? 
sorry if my english is not so good. its not my first language by the way.

Comment: What names of 'customized' layouts you have tried? What do you mean that they do nothing? What behavior do you expect?

Comment: I mean they are just empty spaces that do nothing. i can insert them to my ui but if I add a widget (like a push button) in them they don't act like a layout. they don't expand or don't keep the widget position. but what I want is I need to put my whole program in a layout in the corner of window and put another program in rest of empty spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt Designer doesn't support custom layouts yet.  It has been requested, but no work has started on implementing this.

You *can* create a custom widget designer plug-in that uses your layout, although I don't think it will behave well in Qt Designer; see [Adding Qt Designer Plugins](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/adding-plugins.html).

You can derive from `QLayout` and implement everything *by hand* but Qt Designer won't support custom layouts.

Comment: if custom layouts are not supported in Qt designer why they are exist there?

Comment: Unless something happened in Qt 5.3.2 I don't see any customized layouts in my designer and I use Qt 5.3.1. In my designer I have only `Vertical Layout`, `Horizontal Layout`, `Grid Layout` and `Form Layout`. What Qt version are you using? Can you post a screenshot with your *customized layouts*?

Comment: I bet he calls these 4 layouts 'customized'

Comment: yes ezee is right. they are not customized? but when i right click in my window i can use these layouts. but in widget bar i can use them like widgets. i thought they are custom!! so what should i do???

Comment: They are not custom, they are built in the `Designer`. As you can't use custom layouts in the designer you have 2 options: stick with the available layouts or make the widgets you need to use the layout custom. What you could also try is create custom `Qt Designer` plugin that is nothing but a `QWidget` using your custom layout. Although I can't say for sure as I didn't do it yet it is hard to believe that inside `Qt Designer` it will behave as you expect.

Comment: thank you dear Jacob. now I know what to do. I thought this layouts are custom but now i get it.

Comment: Unfortunately they are not. I also spent a few hours some days ago till I figured it out. Hopefully they will add this feature in the future releases.

Comment: Hop so. it will really help.